# Shifting the frame range of a Camera track

Tags: camera, keyframes, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I'm having a issue with getting the camera track to work properly once the frame ranges have been shifted. 
The situation is, I have been given a shot to track (for the example lets say its 400 frames), once the footage has been tracked and work was started on the shot the client decides to extend the shot, and **add an additional 25 frames to the start of the shot**.
So I do not want to loose and have to redo all my tracking, so I update the footage to the new extended cut with the additional 25 frames at the start. The first problem was that my tracked keyframes are still on frames 1-400, but the footage is shifted, so to fix this I got to the footage tab in the tracking window and **under footage settings set the start time to 26 and frame offset to 25**. now my tracked frames are lined up with the appropriate locations of the footage 26-425.
I then grab all my existing trackers from frame 26, and use them to track backwards to frame 1. everything looks good in the tracking window, I Solve the Camera motion and my solve error stays the same, so all appears to be working until I look at the camera in the 3D view, the new track is working well for frames 26-425, but **from frames 1-25 the camera motion isn't tracked it appears to just be sliding at a constant motion** as if extrapolated from the motion going into frame 26.
I understand that due to the offset I gave the frames Blender is likely looking at these frames as if they are -24-0 rather than 1-25, so I'm assuming that internal math is messing up the camera solve. But if thats the case than how can anyone properly adjust a camera track frame range? 
**So did I go about adding additional frames to the beginning of a camera track the wrong way? if so how else can it be done? or is there a trick that I am missing to getting the camera solve to work when the footage has been offset? Any help would be appreciated. 
 Thank you**